# 12.1 VectorPlot - How to show differing magnitudes in the new implementation

Tags: plotting, vector, vector-calculus

I'm graphing vector fields for a class. Magnitude is important at least initially. In 12.0 and earlier VectorPlot plotted the different magnitudes as length. In 12.1 VectorPlot represents magnitude by color. Nice options too, but I can't figure out how to get the vector fields to show vector magnitude. VectorScaling and VectorScale don't seem to help. Thanks.

Comment: To get vectors of different length, use: `VectorScaling -> Automatic`

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll give it a try.