# VectorScaling on VectorPlot produces vectors of wrong length

Tags: plotting, vector

I'm trying to plot the following VectorField:

```
VectorPlot[{x/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], y/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

I want to use a VectorScaling-option such that vectors are displayed accoring to their length. Obviously, all vectors in this specific vector plot should have the same length, as they are normalized.
I tried to achieve this using the options

```
VectorScaling->Automatic
```

This yields the following output:
[image: VectorSclaing Automatic]
The vectors have **different lengths** (and the colors match this). Why does this happen? The options "Linear", "Log" and "Sqrt" yield similar results. Is this an artifact of calculation inaccuracies? If so, how may I compensate for this?
If I don't use any VectorScaling-option, then all the vectors have the same length (which is the default), but the colors still vary.
I'm using Wolfram Mathematica 12.3.

Addendum: I understand that getting rid of "VectorScaling->Automatic" would yield vectors of constant length. Though I'd like to plot three different vector fields in such a way, that the length of the plottet vectors relates to the real length. So I need some sort of vector scaling for this field of constant length, too.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/239039/4999. This has some discussions of the older `VectorScale` option that might be helpful: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/71787/4999

Comment: Yeah, at the end I just downloaded Mathematica 11 which did the job. Don't know how to achieve what I wanted in 12.3. VectorScaling->Automatic does not do the job if you want other vectorplots with the same scaling to compare them. @MichaelE2

Comment: Your vectors aren't all the same length. :-) They vary from 0.9999999999999998 to 1.0000000000000002 in length.  Floating point math is fun.

Comment: Yes, that's what I guessed, too. Can I explicitley tell Mathematica how to map vector length to arrow length?

Answer (score 0):

```
f1[x_, y_] := x/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2];
f2[x_, y_] := y/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2];



p1 = VectorPlot[{f1[x, y], f2[x, y]}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
      VectorScale -> {Automatic, Automatic, #1 &}, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

```
p2 = VectorPlot[{f1[x, y], f2[x, y]}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
  VectorScale -> {Automatic, Automatic, #2 &}, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

**Finally**

```
Show[p1, p2]
```

[image]

Comment: @ Babelfish i hope this solve it !

Comment: Ahem, I think I did not formulate my problem explicitly enough. Your plot shows vectors of _different_ length - but they should all have the same length. Though I don't really understand whats going on, anyway.